# Does Beta function depends on the physical process we consider?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, renormalization

Given a theory, i.e. an interaction, we normally say that we can compute its Callan-Symanzik $\beta $ function. The process  can be sketched as(here I follow the notation in Weinberg, Vol 2.):

1. Calculate the amplitude $\Gamma ( E,x,g,m)$ of a process possesing loop integral, which may be divergent,
2. Choose a sliding scale $\mu $, then define the coupling constant $g_{\mu }$ according to the $\mu $ we choose, this $g_{\mu }$ may include infinities,
3. Present our orginal coupling amplitude $\Gamma $ as the function of $g_{\mu }$ and $\mu $, which $\Gamma ( E,x,g_{\mu } ,m,\mu )$ is now convergent,
4. Find the relation between the coupling constant of two scales $\mu ,\mu '$, present $g_{\mu '}$ as the a function $g_{\mu '} =G( g_{\mu } ,\mu '/\mu ,m/\mu )$,
5. Calculate the $\beta $ function according to the definition \begin{equation*}
   \beta ( g_{\mu }) =\beta ( g_{\mu } ,0) \equiv \left[\frac{\partial }{\partial z} G( g_{\mu } ,z,m/\mu )\right]_{z=1} .
   \end{equation*}

So my question is, does the $\beta$ function we have calculated depends on the specific physical process(like scattering process) we have choosen in the first step? It seems that it must not depend on the process, but why? To make the question clear, I give a specific example here.

Consider a scalar $\phi^4$ theory, whose Lagrangian is given by:
\begin{equation*}
\mathcal{L} =-\frac{1}{2} \partial _{\lambda } \phi \partial ^{\lambda } \phi -\frac{1}{2} m^{2} \phi ^{2} -\frac{1}{4!} g\phi ^{4} .
\end{equation*}
Then we consider the scattering process $\phi \phi \rightarrow \phi \phi $, at one loop order, the $S$ matrix of this process is given by:
\begin{equation*}
S(q_{1} q_{2}\rightarrow q'_{1} q'_{2} )=\frac{-\mathrm{i} (2\pi )^{4} \delta ^{4}( q'_{1} +q'_{2} -q_{1} -q_{2})}{(2\pi )^{6}( 16E'_{1} E'_{2} E_{1} E_{2})^{1/2}} F(q_{1} q_{2}\rightarrow q'_{1} q'_{2} ),
\end{equation*}
Where
\begin{equation*}
F=g-\frac{g^{2}}{32\pi ^{2}}\int _{0}^{1} \ \mathrm{d} x\left\{\ln\left(\frac{\Lambda ^{2}}{m^{2} -sx(1-x)}\right) +\ln\left(\frac{\Lambda ^{2}}{m^{2} -tx(1-x)}\right) +\ln\left(\frac{\Lambda ^{2}}{m^{2} -ux(1-x)}\right) -3\right\} +\mathcal{O} (g^{3} ).
\end{equation*}
Here $s,t,u$ are Mandelstam variables, $x$ is the Feynman parameter. Then we define the renormalized coupling $g_{\mu }$ at the point $s=t=u=-\mu ^{2}$:
\begin{equation*}
g_{\mu } \equiv F(s=t=u=-\mu ^{2} )=g-\frac{3g^{2}}{32\pi ^{2}}\int _{0}^{1}\mathrm{d} x\left\{\ln\left(\frac{\Lambda ^{2}}{m^{2} +\mu x( 1-x)}\right) -1\right\} +\mathcal{O} (g^{3} ),
\end{equation*}
Consider $g_{\mu }$ at another scale $\mu '$, we can present it with $g_{\mu }$ and give $G$.
\begin{equation*}
g_{\mu '} =g_{\mu } -\frac{3g_{\mu }^{2}}{32\pi ^{2}}\int _{0}^{1}\ln\left(\frac{m^{2} +\mu ^{2} x( 1-x)}{m^{2} +\mu ^{\prime 2} x( 1-x)}\right) +\mathcal{O} (g_{\mu }^{3} )=G( g_{\mu } ,\mu '/\mu ,m/\mu )
\end{equation*}
Then according to the definition of $\beta $ function:
\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
\beta \left( g_{\mu } ,\frac{m}{\mu }\right) & =-\frac{\partial }{\partial z}\left[\frac{3g_{\mu }^{2}}{32\pi ^{2}}\int _{0}^{1}\mathrm{d} x\ln\left(\frac{( m/\mu )^{2} +x( 1-x)}{( m/\mu )^{2} +z^{2} x( 1-x)}\right)\right]_{z=1}\\
 & =\frac{3g_{\mu }^{2}}{16\pi ^{2}}\int _{0}^{1}\mathrm{d} x\frac{\mu ^{2} x( 1-x)}{m^{2} +\mu ^{2} x( 1-x)} +\mathcal{O} (g_{\mu }^{3} ).
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}
When $\mu \gg m$, we have the $\beta ( g_{\mu })$ in normal sense at order $g^{2}$.
\begin{equation*}
\beta ( g_{\mu }) =\frac{3g_{\mu }^{2}}{16\pi ^{2}} +\cdots .
\end{equation*}
So we can see this process seems to depend on which amplitude we choose to calculate, from $F\rightarrow g_{\mu }( F)\rightarrow G( g_{\mu } ,\mu '/\mu )$. Although the first two terms of the series expansion of $\beta ( g_{\mu })$ doesn't depend the gauge and definition of $\mu $ we choose(c.f. Weinberg 18.3.30), but here it means if we choose $\mu $ like $2s=2t=2u=-\mu ^{2}$, the $\beta $ function will still have the same form. If we choose another process, like $\phi \rightarrow \phi $ or $\phi \phi \phi \rightarrow \phi \phi \phi $, follow the same procedure, can we reproduce the same $\beta $ function?

In counterterm approach, we can choose the counterterm to eliminate all the divergence in the renormalized Lagrangian to all order, which means the counterterm cannot depend on the process we have chosen, which is proven. However, the case here is slightly different, although we can define the $\beta $ with respect to the counter term(P&S 12.53), but our choose of the scale $\mu $ is rather free, we can have the RG method without the help of the normal counterterm approach, namely we can use only the bare theory to give the RG equation.

So my question:

**Do the $\beta $ function dependent on which process we choose? If yes,then what do we mean by the $\beta $ function of a theory? If not, why does a process "dependent" calculation lead to process independent result? And can we calculate the $\beta $ function by the process $\phi \rightarrow \phi $ or $\phi \phi \phi \rightarrow \ \phi \phi \phi $, or even $\left\langle\text{VAC} ,\text{out}|\text{VAC},\text{in}\right\rangle$?**

P.S. In P&S, it seems that $\beta$ doesn't depend on the specific process, but I didn't use that book and cannot understand his arguements.